# Slow Write Speed(<2 MB/s) on Unencrypted and LUKS Encrypted ext4 filesystems using mdadm Software RAID1 Debian 8 Dell PowerEdge T330 Server

Tags: debian, ext4, io, luks, mdadm

We have installed Debian 8 on a new Dell PowerEdge T330, there are two partitions, / and /var, in a RAID1 array using mdadm. During testing the primary applications: mysql and tomcat were stopped. We are getting abysmal write performance from both partitions although the read performance is adequate. This is the observations from one of two identical servers setup the same way. Any help would be appreciated.

**Performance**

root@bcmdit-519:/home/bcmdit# FILE=/tmp/test_data && dd bs=16k \ 
                count=102400 oflag=direct if=/dev/zero of=$FILE && \
                rm $FILE && FILE=/var/tmp/test_data && dd bs=16k \ 
                count=102400 oflag=direct if=/dev/zero of=$FILE && rm $FILE

```
102400+0 records in
102400+0 records out
1677721600 bytes (1.7 GB) copied, 886.418 s, 1.9 MB/s

102400+0 records in
102400+0 records out
1677721600 bytes (1.7 GB) copied, 894.832 s, 1.9 MB/s
```

root@bcmdit-519:/home/bcmdit# hdparm -t /dev/sda ; hdparm -t /dev/sdb ; hdparm -t /dev/md0 ; hdparm -t /dev/md1

```
/dev/sda:

    Timing buffered disk reads: 394 MB in  3.00 seconds = 131.15 MB/sec

/dev/sdb:

    Timing buffered disk reads: 394 MB in  3.01 seconds = 131.05 MB/sec

/dev/md0:

    Timing buffered disk reads: 398 MB in  3.00 seconds = 132.45 MB/sec

/dev/md1:

    Timing buffered disk reads: 318 MB in  3.00 seconds = 106.00 MB/sec
```

**References**

https://severfault.com/questions/832117/how-increase-write-speed-of-raid1-mdadm
https://wiki.mikejung.biz/Software_RAID
[Write access time slow on RAID1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/341315/write-access-time-slow-on-raid1)
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=173791
et al...

**Configuration**

Encryption was setup using:

root@bcmdit-519:/home/bcmdit# cryptsetup luksDump UUID=1e7b64ac-f187-4fac-9712-8e0dacadfca7|grep -E 'Cipher|Hash'

```
Cipher name:    aes
Cipher mode:    xts-plain64
Hash spec:      sha1
```

Config snippets

```
root@bcmdit-519:/home/bcmdit# facter virtual productname lsbdistid \
                     lsbdistrelease processor0 blockdevice_sda_model \  
                     blockdevice_sdb_model bios_version && uname -a && uptime
----------

    bios_version => 2.4.3
    blockdevice_sda_model => ST1000NX0423
    blockdevice_sdb_model => ST1000NX0423
    lsbdistid => Debian
    lsbdistrelease => 8.10
    processor0 => Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1230 v6 @ 3.50GHz
    productname => PowerEdge T330
    virtual => physical
    Linux bcmdit-519 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.51-3 (2017-12-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux
     14:45:58 up  2:49,  2 users,  load average: 0.06, 0.17, 0.44

 root@bcmdit-519:/home/bcmdit# grep GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT /etc/default/grub

    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet erst_disable elevator=deadline"

root@bcmdit-519:/home/bcmdit# free -m         

             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         32202       1532      30670          9         17        369
-/+ buffers/cache:       1145      31056
Swap:            0          0          0
```

root@bcmdit-519:/home/bcmdit# parted /dev/sda print

```
    Model: ATA ST1000NX0423 (scsi)
    Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
    Partition Table: msdos
    Disk Flags: 

    Number  Start   End     Size   Type      File system  Flags
     1      1049kB  500GB   500GB  primary                boot, raid
     2      500GB   1000GB  500GB  extended
     5      500GB   1000GB  500GB  logical                raid
```

root@bcmdit-519:/home/bcmdit# parted /dev/sdb print

```
    Model: ATA ST1000NX0423 (scsi)
    Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
    Partition Table: msdos
    Disk Flags: 

    Number  Start   End     Size   Type      File system  Flags
     1      1049kB  500GB   500GB  primary                raid
     2      500GB   1000GB  500GB  extended
     5      500GB   1000GB  500GB  logical                raid

----------
```

root@bcmdit-519:/home/bcmdit# cat /proc/mdstat

```
    Personalities : [raid1] 
    md1 : active raid1 sda5[0] sdb5[1]
          488249344 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
          bitmap: 3/4 pages [12KB], 65536KB chunk

    md0 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdb1[1]
          488248320 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
          bitmap: 2/4 pages [8KB], 65536KB chunk

    unused devices: <none>

root@bcmdit-519:/home/bcmdit# mdadm --query --detail /dev/md0

    /dev/md0:
            Version : 1.2
      Creation Time : Mon Apr 16 13:46:51 2018
         Raid Level : raid1
         Array Size : 488248320 (465.63 GiB 499.97 GB)
      Used Dev Size : 488248320 (465.63 GiB 499.97 GB)
       Raid Devices : 2
      Total Devices : 2
        Persistence : Superblock is persistent

      Intent Bitmap : Internal

        Update Time : Tue May 15 14:26:47 2018
              State : clean 
     Active Devices : 2
    Working Devices : 2
     Failed Devices : 0
      Spare Devices : 0

               Name : bcmdit-519:0  (local to host bcmdit-519)
               UUID : afd3968c:2e8b191d:4504f21e:255b6470
             Events : 1703

        Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
           0       8        1        0      active sync   /dev/sda1
           1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1

 root@bcmdit-519:/home/bcmdit# mdadm --query --detail /dev/md1

    /dev/md1: 

            Version : 1.2
      Creation Time : Mon Apr 16 13:47:06 2018
         Raid Level : raid1
         Array Size : 488249344 (465.63 GiB 499.97 GB)
      Used Dev Size : 488249344 (465.63 GiB 499.97 GB)
       Raid Devices : 2
      Total Devices : 2
        Persistence : Superblock is persistent

      Intent Bitmap : Internal

        Update Time : Tue May 15 14:15:11 2018
              State : active 
     Active Devices : 2
    Working Devices : 2
     Failed Devices : 0
      Spare Devices : 0

               Name : bcmdit-519:1  (local to host bcmdit-519)
               UUID : e46f968a:e8fff775:ecee9cfb:4ad88574
             Events : 2659

        Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
           0       8        5        0      active sync   /dev/sda5
           1       8       21        1      active sync   /dev/sdb5
```

root@bcmdit-519:/home/bcmdit# cat /etc/crypttab

```
    crypt1 UUID=1e7b64ac-f187-4fac-9712-8e0dacadfca7 /root/.crypt1 luks
```

root@bcmdit-519:/home/bcmdit# grep -v '^#' /etc/fstab

```
    UUID=c6baa173-8ea6-4598-a965-eee728a93d69 /               ext4    defaults,errors=remount-ro 0       1
    /dev/sr0        /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
    /dev/mapper/crypt1 /var ext4 defaults,errors=remount-ro 0       2
    /var/swapfile1 none swap sw,nofail 0       0
```

root@bcmdit-519:/home/bcmdit# smartctl -a /dev/sda|head -n 20

```
    smartctl 6.4 2014-10-07 r4002 [x86_64-linux-3.16.0-4-amd64] (local build)
    Copyright (C) 2002-14, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

    === START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
    Device Model:     ST1000NX0423
    Serial Number:    W4713QXE
    LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 0abb06247
    Add. Product Id:  DELL(tm)
    Firmware Version: NA07
    User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
    Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
    Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
    Form Factor:      2.5 inches
    Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
    ATA Version is:   ACS-3 (minor revision not indicated)
    SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
    Local Time is:    Tue May 15 14:29:03 2018 PDT
    SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
    SMART support is: Enabled
```

root@bcmdit-519:/home/bcmdit# smartctl -a /dev/sdb|head -n 20

```
    smartctl 6.4 2014-10-07 r4002 [x86_64-linux-3.16.0-4-amd64] (local build)
    Copyright (C) 2002-14, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

    === START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
    Device Model:     ST1000NX0423
    Serial Number:    W4714VDQ
    LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 0abf99927
    Add. Product Id:  DELL(tm)
    Firmware Version: NA07
    User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
    Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
    Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
    Form Factor:      2.5 inches
    Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
    ATA Version is:   ACS-3 (minor revision not indicated)
    SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
    Local Time is:    Tue May 15 14:29:11 2018 PDT
    SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
    SMART support is: Enabled
```

**Update 1**

With 16M

```
root@bcmdit-519:/tmp# FILE=/tmp/test_data \
&& dd bs=16M count=102 oflag=direct if=/dev/zero of=$FILE \
&& rm $FILE \
&& FILE=/var/tmp/test_data \
&& dd bs=16M count=102 oflag=direct if=/dev/zero of=$FILE \
&& rm $FILE
102+0 records in
102+0 records out
1711276032 bytes (1.7 GB) copied, 16.6394 s, 103 MB/s
102+0 records in
102+0 records out
1711276032 bytes (1.7 GB) copied, 17.8649 s, 95.8 MB/s
```

**Update 2**
Seagate drive serial number found SMART indicates an Enterprise grade drive:
https://www.cnet.com/products/seagate-enterprise-capacity-2-5-hdd-v-3-1tb-sata-512n/specs/

**Update 3**
I found that drive write cacheing was off, but by setting it to on:

```
hdparm -W1 /dev/sd*
```

I get much better results with bs=16k now

```
root@bcmdit-519:/home/bcmdit# FILE=/tmp/test_data && dd bs=16k count=102400 oflag=direct if=/dev/zero of=$FILE && rm $FILE
102400+0 records in         
102400+0 records out
1677721600 bytes (1.7 GB) copied, 14.0708 s, 119 MB/s
```

**Update 4**

root@ecm-oscar-519:/home/bcmdit# cryptsetup benchmark

```
# Tests are approximate using memory only (no storage IO).
PBKDF2-sha1      1394382 iterations per second
PBKDF2-sha256     923042 iterations per second
PBKDF2-sha512     728177 iterations per second
PBKDF2-ripemd160  804122 iterations per second
PBKDF2-whirlpool  313569 iterations per second
#  Algorithm | Key |  Encryption |  Decryption
     aes-cbc   128b  1149.9 MiB/s  3655.8 MiB/s
 serpent-cbc   128b    99.6 MiB/s   743.4 MiB/s
 twofish-cbc   128b   219.0 MiB/s   400.0 MiB/s
     aes-cbc   256b   867.5 MiB/s  2904.5 MiB/s
 serpent-cbc   256b    99.6 MiB/s   742.6 MiB/s
 twofish-cbc   256b   218.9 MiB/s   399.8 MiB/s
     aes-xts   256b  3615.1 MiB/s  3617.3 MiB/s
 serpent-xts   256b   710.8 MiB/s   705.0 MiB/s
 twofish-xts   256b   388.1 MiB/s   394.5 MiB/s
     aes-xts   512b  2884.9 MiB/s  2888.1 MiB/s
 serpent-xts   512b   710.7 MiB/s   704.7 MiB/s
 twofish-xts   512b   388.0 MiB/s   394.3 MiB/s
```

Comment: Please could you format the blocks of output properly. Select the blocks and use the `{}` to turn it into fixed-width output (like you'd see on a terminal). It's _so much easier_ to read and digest.

Comment: is mdadm balancing? Show it's setup, status, logs, dmesg, SMART. Also try bs=16m instead of bs=16k... I'd use luks/btrfs or lvm/luks/ext4 ..

Comment: @user1133275 what is needed from dmesg? mdadm --query --detail output has been provided, what else is needed?

Comment: 2MB/sec using 16K write operations is 125 IO operations/sec.  That's actually a pretty good number for a consumer-grade SATA disk, which is what I assume you're running.  7,200 RPM SATA disks usually can reach a max of about 70 IO operations/sec, but the fact that you're doing sequential 16K writes probably means the disk is able to coalesce a lot of the individual write operations you send to it. Try doing single-block-sized writes to *random* locations so the disk can't coalesce data and the IO rate could drop to 30kb/sec or less.

Comment: @AndrewHenle The drive claims to be Enterprise grade

Comment: 2MB/s is abysmal for even an old IDE drive. Is this a brand new disk and server? I get 50+ MB/s writes any time of the day on consumer grade hardware which was obsolete when my grandma was dating the grandpa.

Comment: @user1133275 I supplied uname -a, but here is -r: 3.16.0-4-amd64

Comment: smartctl -a is more about the numbers after the line 20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you ask dd for `bs=16K` and `oflag=direct` you are asking for many small writes, this is what HDDs are bad at and what SSDs are good at.

You can use LVMCache to get the benefit of both (up to the SSD size)

If you use `bs=16M` or no `oflag` then the writes are split/combined/cached in RAM and written at an optimal size.

[Why is dd using direct slower writing to disk than to a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110266/why-is-dd-using-direct-slower-writing-to-disk-than-to-a-file?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

for example;

```
> dd if=/dev/zero of=test.bin bs=16k count=1000 oflag=direct
1000+0 records in
1000+0 records out
16384000 bytes (16 MB, 16 MiB) copied, 3.19453 s, 5.1 MB/s

> dd if=/dev/zero of=test.bin bs=16M count=1 oflag=direct
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
16777216 bytes (17 MB, 16 MiB) copied, 0.291366 s, 57.6 MB/s

> dd if=/dev/zero of=test.bin bs=16k count=1000
1000+0 records in
1000+0 records out
16384000 bytes (16 MB, 16 MiB) copied, 0.0815558 s, 201 MB/s

> uname -r
4.14.41-130
```

Comment: You should test your theories before posting, as everything you wrote has no basis in reality. Block size makes a difference, but nowhere near what the OP is seeing. Here are two examples from a very ancient system, using a consumer grade 500GB 7200 RPM SATA drive:

Comment: $ dd if=/dev/zero of=test.bin bs=16k count=100000 oflag=direct
100000+0 records in
100000+0 records out
1638400000 bytes (1.6 GB, 1.5 GiB) copied, 50.4272 s, 32.5 MB/s

Comment: $ dd if=/dev/zero of=test.bin bs=16M count=100 oflag=direct
100+0 records in
100+0 records out
1677721600 bytes (1.7 GB, 1.6 GiB) copied, 17.9688 s, 93.4 MB/s

Comment: As you can see, `bs` makes a difference, but it cannot explain horrific 2 MB/s in the OP. 16M happens to be the cache size on my HDD, so that's the optimal value for my system. But SATA drive controllers are intelligent enough to bundle small block write requests into larger operations, they have been doing that for decades by now.

Comment: Well, all I can say is that your system is seriously messed up, if small `bs` brings it down to a grinding halt.

Comment: The above 2 test cases are from 4.16.5, but as long as I can remember (since 1x series kernels) they were never that slow with small vs large `bs` values. I am doing this for a living for 20+ years and never saw write speeds this slow!

Comment: @ajeh disk write cacheing was off, so the performance was abysmal. Perhaps because it was in software raid1 using mdadm?

Comment: Great that you found the RC, but I kind of doubt that software raid should have no caching. That would make no sense at all and defeat the purpose.

Comment: Yes, this comment is suggesting small write block sizes for SSDs which would lead to considerable write amplification factor and faster degradation.  Modern HDDs, on the other hand, do not have blocks larger than 4096 bytes.

Comment: @Michael the 5/60/200 MB/s example is on ~2018 10TB Seagate (SMR likely)

Comment: @user1133275 hah, that was the #1 guess of mine ("SMR?")... just to add some usefulness:
https://blog.westerndigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/2020_04_22_WD_SMR_SKUs_1Slide.pdf
http://www.mobibrw.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/3.5SATAHDDDatabase2018-10-24byjerrytsao.xlsx.zip

Answer (score 0):

Using [`pv` (man page)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv) utility like so:

```
pv --average-rate < /dev/urandom > /mdX-MountPoint/SomeFileName
```

may prove to be more effective method of measuring the speed than your [`dd` (man page)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html).

I edited the input file to be random data, which is better than static zeroes.

---

The problem with [`dd` (man page)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html) is that you must adjust the block size.

While with [`pv` (man page)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv) that is not the case as it establishes maximum speed itself for the best throughput.

Comment: What does `/dev/urandom` have to do with HDD write speed?

Comment: @ajeh if the file system has compression enabled it will make a huge difference